# Converting Spark DF too Pandas DF and other way - Performance

Tags: pandas, azure-databricks, pyspark

Trying to convert Spark DF with 8m records to Pandas DF

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
sourcePandas = srcDF.select("*").toPandas()
```

Takes almost 2 minutes

And other way from Pandas to Spark DF

```
finalDF = spark.createDataFrame(sourcePandas)
```

takes too long and never finishes.

sourcePandas

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 42 columns):
CONSIGNMENT_PK     10 non-null int32
CERTIFICATE_NO     10 non-null object
ACTOR_NAME         10 non-null object
GENERATOR_FK       10 non-null int32
TRANSPORTER_FK     10 non-null int32
RECEIVER_FK        10 non-null int32
REC_POST_CODE      0 non-null object
WASTEDESC          10 non-null object
WASTE_FK           10 non-null int32
GEN_LICNUM         0 non-null object
VOLUME             10 non-null int32
MEASURE            10 non-null object
WASTE_TYPE         10 non-null object
WASTE_ADD          0 non-null object
CONTAMINENT1_FK    0 non-null float64
CONTAMINENT2_FK    0 non-null float64
CONTAMINENT3_FK    0 non-null float64
CONTAMINENT4_FK    0 non-null float64
TREATMENT_FK       10 non-null int32
ANZSICODE_FK       10 non-null int32
VEH1_REGNO         10 non-null object
VEH1_LICNO         0 non-null object
VEH2_REGNO         0 non-null object
VEH2_LICNO         0 non-null object
GEN_SIGNEE         0 non-null object
GEN_DATE           10 non-null datetime64[ns]
TRANS_SIGNEE       0 non-null object
TRANS_DATE         10 non-null datetime64[ns]
REC_SIGNEE         0 non-null object
REC_DATE           10 non-null datetime64[ns]
DATECREATED        10 non-null datetime64[ns]
DISCREPANCY        0 non-null object
APPROVAL_NUMBER    0 non-null object
TR_TYPE            10 non-null object
REC_WASTE_FK       10 non-null int32
REC_WASTE_TYPE     10 non-null object
REC_VOLUME         10 non-null int32
REC_MEASURE        10 non-null object
DATE_RECEIVED      10 non-null datetime64[ns]
DATE_SCANNED       0 non-null datetime64[ns]
HAS_IMAGE          10 non-null object
LASTMODIFIED       10 non-null datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](7), float64(4), int32(10), object(21)
memory usage: 3.0+ KB
```

srcDF

```
|-- CONSIGNMENT_PK: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- CERTIFICATE_NO: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ACTOR_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- GENERATOR_FK: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- TRANSPORTER_FK: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- RECEIVER_FK: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- REC_POST_CODE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- WASTEDESC: string (nullable = true)
 |-- WASTE_FK: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- GEN_LICNUM: string (nullable = true)
 |-- VOLUME: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- MEASURE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- WASTE_TYPE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- WASTE_ADD: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CONTAMINENT1_FK: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- CONTAMINENT2_FK: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- CONTAMINENT3_FK: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- CONTAMINENT4_FK: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- TREATMENT_FK: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- ANZSICODE_FK: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- VEH1_REGNO: string (nullable = true)
 |-- VEH1_LICNO: string (nullable = true)
 |-- VEH2_REGNO: string (nullable = true)
 |-- VEH2_LICNO: string (nullable = true)
 |-- GEN_SIGNEE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- GEN_DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- TRANS_SIGNEE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TRANS_DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- REC_SIGNEE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- REC_DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- DATECREATED: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- DISCREPANCY: string (nullable = true)
 |-- APPROVAL_NUMBER: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TR_TYPE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- REC_WASTE_FK: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- REC_WASTE_TYPE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- REC_VOLUME: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- REC_MEASURE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DATE_RECEIVED: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- DATE_SCANNED: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- HAS_IMAGE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LASTMODIFIED: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Cluster size

[image]

Comment: What are the shapes of `srcDF` and `finalDF`? What is the cluster configuration?

Comment: @Dave: Updated the question with required info.

Answer (score 0):

Collecting to pandas and re-parallelizing to the cluster will have a memory high water mark of approx 2 times the storage cost of the pandas DF. Ten rows of your dataframe is 3KB, so 8M will be ~2.5G. Doubling to get the high water mark takes us to ~5G. The default spark driver memory is 1G, which is too low for what you want to do, causing the JVM to thrash GC:

1. Push the [Application Property](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties) `spark.driver.memory` up to 8G and it should work.
2. Revaluate why you want to collect all this data to the driver. Can you use a [pandas UDF in a GROUPED_MAP](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf)?